# Bash Script Works Alone But Not When Executed From Python, Until Loop Not Recognizing Variable, Why?

Tags: python, bash, loops, variables, execute

I'm having no problem running the bash script from python but here's the deal... When I execute the bash script on its own, it runs fine. When I execute it from python, a variable and until loop are supposed to work together, but for some reason when loop=10 the until loop doesn't recognize it and it keeps looping infinitely.

```
cd_slash()
{
     loop=0
     until [ $loop == 10 ] 
     do
          #example
          loop=`expr $loop + 1`
          echo $loop
}
```

cd_slash

So to reiterate, when executed from the terminal with no python, the until loop loops until loop=10. When executed from python, the until loop goes on forever and loop+=1 infinitely. Both call and os.system() run it but it won't run correctly, and only when called or executed from the python script.

Comment: working fine if `done` is put after `echo` command in python2.7

Comment: Assuming that the missing `done` is a typo.  It could be that you are picking-up a different version of the script from python.  Are you specifying the full path-name in both cases?